# Example of a manifold satisfying some Ricci curvature condition

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with Ricci curvature $R_{ij}$ and scalar curvature $R$. Suppose $X$ is a smooth vector field on $M$ satisfying the condition
$$R_{ij}(\nabla^iX^j)\leq cR,$$ where $c$ is a constant. Now I am not able to find a non-trivial example of a manifold that satisfies this type of condition. I earnestly request everyone for providing this example.

Comment: Could you elaborate? This is true for the flat metric. Does the constant depend on $X$?

Comment: It seems that every Ricci soliton satisfies the condition,

Comment: @ArcticChar: Can you please elaborate how to prove that every Ricci soliton satisfies the condition.

Comment: @Deane. The constant is not dependent on $X$. It can be any constant. My question is there any Riemannian manifold satisfying this condition. Here the Ricci and Scalar curvature should not vanish, otherwise it holds trivially.

Comment: If the left side is not always zero and $c$ is a constant, independent of $X$, then the inequality cannot hold. Suppose $X$ is vector field where the left side is positive (if it is negative, replace $X$ by $-X$). If you replace $X$ by $aX$, where $a$ is a positive scalar, then for $a$ sufficiently large, the inequality will be false.

Comment: @Deane. Actually I am not saying that this condition holds for any vector field. My question is there any manifold satisfying this condition for some vector fields?

Comment: Could you state your question rigorously with all the quantifiers? I’m pretty confused.

Comment: @Deane: Question: Is there any manifold with a vector field $X$ such that  $R_{ij}(\nabla^iX^j)\leq cR$ for some constant $c$?

Comment: This holds for any vector field on a closed Riemannian manifold with positive scalar curvature, because the left side is bounded from above, so you just have to set $c$ sufficiently large.

Comment: @Deane. Thank you very much.